# Creating a Route from_path not working as expected

Tags: rust, yew

I'm trying to redirect the user to a URL, which seems like it should be simple. My code is quite straightforward:

```
Ok(url) => {
   let params: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
   if params.is_empty() {log::info!("Params is empty, which is proper");};
   log::info!("Redirecting to {}", url.clone());
   let redir_route = match Route::from_path(url.as_str(), &params) {
       Some(routable) => { routable },
       None => { 
           log::info!("Failed to get route");
           Route::Home
       }
   };
   user_ctx_for_run_post.set_next(redir_route);
},
```

The source for `from_path` appears to be simple:
Check to make sure that params is empty, then return a Routable object if so. If params is not empty, return `None`. So I create the empty `params`, make sure it's empty, then call `from_path` and I get `None` every single time.

Is there an easier way to do this? What's the appropriate way to do the JS equivalent of `"window.location.href = ‘https://exampleURL.com/’;"` in Yew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find web apis in [web_sys](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/).

The apis you're asking for, are in [Window::location](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.Window.html#method.location) and [Location::herf](https://docs.rs/web-sys/latest/web_sys/struct.Location.html#method.href).

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Note: All (or at least almost all) Rust's web frameworks are based on web_sys

Comment: Ok, yup, that's the answer.

For completeness, in case anyone as unlearned as me comes along later:

use web_sys::window;

window().unwrap().location().set_href(url.as_str()).unwrap();

And, of course, you should handle the unwraps appropriately instead of just letting them panic.